# How to test BitBucket pull requests?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Is there any tool or plugin for Jenkins that would monitor pull requests in Jenkins and do a build (in my case jslint javascript files) and report to the pull request if there are any errors?

Answer (score 4):

All I can find is https://bitbucket.org/osrf/bitbucket-jenkins

It's active but far from feature complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice plugin for this available at:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin